# Ruby on Rails: Twitter Bootstrap radio buttons not working (selection will not stay)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I'm developing a Ruby on Rails app that is using both Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery UI. As far as my knowledge goes, most (maybe all?) incompatibility issues between the two have been worked out (and I have the latest gems of both installed and included in asset pipeline). This question doesn't really have much to do with jQuery UI, I just thought it may be a good bit of knowledge in case there is a compatibility issue there I am unaware of...

Anyway - I'm simply trying to include a few vertically-stacked radio buttons on a user's page and for some reason the radio button's are acting just like regular buttons. At first I attributed this to a likely typo like `data-toggle="buttons-raadio"` or something silly like that, but upon inspection I didn't see any difference in my code and the suggested format in the [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons). Eventually I got frustrated and just copy-pasted the code (both the HTML and the Javascript to enable the buttons) directly from the [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons) for a litmus test, and I got the same behavior.

So, the if you didn't click the link, the [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons) gives a simple example as follows:

```
    <!-- HTML -->
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Left</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Right</button>
    </div>

    /Javascript
    <script> 
      $('.nav-tabs').button();
    </script>
```

So, what's the deal? Why is the "active" class not being added to the radio-buttons on a click? I do find it interesting that it says to use it on the class `.nav-tabs`, instead of `.btn` (which I tried to no avail, it just messes up the pretty formatting of btn-primary while still not giving the correct functionality), but I'm guessing `.nav-tabs` filters down to buttons somewhere along the line.

Also, so I decided to check the html on the [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons), and sure enough I've got the exact same HTML coupled with the same JavaScript call... I'm at a loss.

Thanks in advance for any and all answers.

-MM

Comment: I think you are applying a wrong class to your DOM elements: in the js the class is `nav-tabs` , I cant see such a class in your html.

Comment: Have you checked that the Bootstrap Javascript file is being loaded?

Comment: @QumaraSixOneTour, I don't disagree with what you're saying - I thought it strange that it call the method on a class that they never talk about once in the documentation. Like I mentioned in the question, I tried doing `<script>$('.btn').button()</script> but that screwed up the other formatting of the button.

Comment: @MarkStratmann, I'm not sure exactly how one would directly test that the file is being loaded, but I've ensured that the bootstrap-sass gem has been installed and I've added the required includes to `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`. I am using some other features of Bootstrap that are working just fine - so unless there is something specific I need to do for the Bootstrap Javascript file that is not included in the general addition of Bootstrap to a rails project, I think everything has been included correctly.

Comment: What about CSS assets , have you included them in the manifest?

Comment: In development, on your chrome browser have you used the development tools to "Inspect element" your page and seen that bootstrap.js is being loaded in the head of your page, also have you checked the javascript console in inspect element to see that there are no errors?

Comment: @MarkStratmann, I've inspected the page and see2 that both bootstrap.js and bootstrap-button.js have been instantiated.

Comment: @QumaraSixOneTour, the functionality that is missing is the "active" class that is not being added to the currently selected button - something that is solely dependent on javascript, not CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done some more research, and this seems to be an issue with compatability between twitter bootstrap and jquery-ui, the specific gems for both as following:

- gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'
- gem "jquery-ui-rails", "~> 4.0.0"

So I didn't actually use the bootstrap/jquery-ui bundled gems out there, which could be part of my issue. On a button click, I would receive a Javascript error:

```
   Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on button prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'toggle' (jquery.js: 552)
   Full trace:
    Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on button prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'toggle' jquery.js:552
    jQuery.extend.error jquery.js:552
    (anonymous function) jquery.ui.widget.js:183
    jQuery.extend.each jquery.js:661
    jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery.js:272
    $.fn.(anonymous function) jquery.ui.widget.js:179
    (anonymous function) bootstrap-button.js:93
    jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:3333
    elemData.handle.eventHandle jquery.js:2942
```

And if I instantiated each button with the `.button()` method, I would then received a different error:

```
    Uncaught Error: no such method 'toggle' for button widget instance (jquery.js:552)
    Full error trace:
     Uncaught Error: no such method 'toggle' for button widget instance jquery.js:552
     jQuery.extend.error jquery.js:552
     (anonymous function) jquery.ui.widget.js:187
     jQuery.extend.each jquery.js:661
     jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery.js:272
     $.fn.(anonymous function) jquery.ui.widget.js:179
     (anonymous function) bootstrap-button.js:93
     jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:3333
     elemData.handle.eventHandle jquery.js:2942
```

To work around this, I've added a `my-button` class to each button, and am doing the click handling myself (keep in mind, you must make sure to add and remove the `active` class based on which button was clicked, which I am doing through the `addClass()` and `removeClass()` methods).

Answer (score 1):

I have altered my answer following your last comment.  Here is an example from one of my sites that is working perfectly.  I have no need to make any kind of call to enable the radio button functionality.  I have included a list of all the bootstrap js files are are being loaded on my page.  Perhaps the bootstrap-button.js file is not being loaded in your site.

```
<head>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<div class="stx-button-row">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
        <button class="btn stx-button active" id="stx-and" type="button">
            AND
        </button>
        <button class="btn stx-button" id="stx-or" type="button">
            OR
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply - this indeed changes the color of the button to indicate that it is selected, but clicking the other buttons still has no effect (it's gotta be something with the javascript, and I feel like it has something to do with the fact that the way the buttons are instantiated, the .button() method is called on the strange '.nav-tabs' class)

Comment: the calling .buttons on nav-tabs is a red herring, you dont need to do that.